# Django 3. Having trouble passing dropdown menu selection from .html to forms

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, django

I'm still new to Django (2 weeks or so). I've been struggling the past few days with passing a string from an html file to forms. My project lets the user choose a state from a dropdown menu (Michigan and Ohio for now, I'll add the rest later). When the state is selected, it will take that string and pull a list of counties of that state from a spreadsheet. This is where the problem lies. I've searched far and wide and I just can't seem to find a solution. The major holdback to many of these solutions is I don't want to "submit" with a button. I want the user to "select" a state, then select a county without a page refresh. I've also included a screenshot of the webpage. So far the dependent dropdowns work perfectly thanks to a youtube tutorial. The "submit" button in the picture is cosmetic for now.

Thanks in advance for helping out. Let me know if you have any questions regarding models or anything else regarding the code.

**views.py**

```
def StateForm_Page(request):
    context = {}
    stateChoice = 'Michigan' //hardcode a state so if the post fails, the function can still find an excel sheet
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        State_Form = StateForm(request.POST)
        stateChoice = State_Form.cleaned_data['stateChoice'] //I think this is where my code is failing
        
    else:
        State_Form = StateForm()


    context['State_Form'] = State_Form 

    dataArray = pd.read_excel(r'C:\filename.xls', sheet_name= stateChoice)
    county_strings = dataArray['County '].values.tolist()
    json_county_strings = json.dumps(county_strings)
    context['json_county_strings'] = json_county_strings
    return render(request, 'StateForm_page.html', context)
```

**StateForm_page.html**

```
<body>

    <form action="" method="POST" name="stateChoice">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ State_Form.as_p }} 
        
    </form>
    
    <script>
var state;
var county;

        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#id_county').empty(); //empties county before state is chosen
           
            $("#id_state").on('change', function(){  //when #id_state is changed...
               
                state = $("#id_state").val(); //assign state with the selection
                
                var countyStrings = JSON.parse('{{ json_county_strings | escapejs }}'); //grabs counties from respective state
           
                var length = countyStrings.length;
                var  i;
                for(i=0; i < length; i++){

                    county = countyStrings[i]; //update county options with spreadsheet values
                    $('#id_county').append(

                        `
                        <option value ="${county}">
                            ${county}
                                
                        </option>
                        `
                    );
                }
            });
        })      
        }

        
    </script>
</body>
```

What the webpage looks like so far:

[image: What the webpage looks like so far]

**Next day changes**

Hey, after putting a few more hours into it, I'm still not having every luck. Per your suggestions, below is what I've added
**views.py**

```
def retrieveState(request):
    statePick = request.GET.get('state')
    

    return JsonResponse(statePick, safe = False)


def StateForm_Page(request):
    context = {}
    stateChoice = []
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        #stateChoice = State_Form.cleaned_data['stateChoice']
        State_Form = StateForm(request.POST)
        stateChoice = retrieveState(request)
        
        
    else:
        stateChoice = 'Michigan'
        State_Form = StateForm()
```

**StateForm_Page.html**

```
               $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'ajax/retrieveState/',
                    data: state,
                    dataType: 'json',
                
                
                    
        
                });
```

Good news is *something* is being triggered on the ajax url I added, but I don't think the function in views is retrieving the ajax data. Any suggestions? Thanks for your help!
[image: Terminal Output]

Comment: To do that you should make ajax request towards server, django alone would be bad solution to do that (at least to my knowledge). [This](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html) is a good tutorial. 
code would go something like this:


    if request.method == 'POST':State_Form = StateForm(request.POST)
        stateChoice = State_Form.cleaned_data['stateChoice']
        data = filter( stateChoiceFunction, stateChoice)
        return JsonResponse(data)

Comment: I've updated my post with some more questions if you have an opportunity. Thanks!